# xamarin android mvvmcross splash screen stuck

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

My app stopped working after upgrade MvvmCross from 6.3.1 to 6.4.0

It is stuck on the splash screen.

// App.cs in core project

```
public class App : MvxApplication
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        // this is not called
    }
}
```

// MainApplication .cs in droid project

```
[Application]
public class MainApplication : MvxAndroidApplication<Setup, AndroidApp>
{
    private string[] permissionsList;

    public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transer)
    : base(handle, transer)
    {       
     // this is called     
    }            
}
```

// Setup.cs in droid project

```
public class Setup : MvxAndroidSetup<AndroidApp>
{
    protected override IMvxAndroidViewPresenter CreateViewPresenter()
    {
        // this is called
        return new MvxAppCompatViewPresenter(AndroidViewAssemblies);
    }
    public override IEnumerable<Assembly> GetViewModelAssemblies()
    {
        return new[] { typeof(App).Assembly };
    }
    protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
    {
        MvxAppCompatSetupHelper.FillTargetFactories(registry);
        base.FillTargetFactories(registry);
    }
}
```

// SplashScreen.cs in droid project

```
[Activity(Label = "SplashScreen", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/AppTheme.Splash", NoHistory = true, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class SplashScreen : MvxSplashScreenAppCompatActivity<MvxAppCompatSetup<App>, App>
{       
     public SplashScreen() : base(Resource.Layout.SplashScreen)
     {
         // this is called
     }
}
```

EDIT: I traced the exception which I guess is breaking the initialization process:

> Could not resolve type with token 01000015 from typeref (expected
>   class 'System.Drawing.Color' in assembly 'System.Drawing.Common,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51')

in

> at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes(System.Reflection.Assembly,bool)
>   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup+<>c.b__55_0
>   (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly) [0x00000] in
>   D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\Core\MvxSetup.cs:392    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2[TSource,TResult].MoveNext
>   () [0x00051] in <715c2ff6913942e6aa8535593b3ef35a>:0    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[TSource].MoveNext ()
>   [0x0004e] in <715c2ff6913942e6aa8535593b3ef35a>:0    at
>   MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup.LoadPlugins
>   (MvvmCross.Plugin.IMvxPluginManager pluginManager) [0x0006a] in
>   D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\Core\MvxSetup.cs:395    at
>   MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup.InitializePluginFramework () [0x00007] in
>   D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\Core\MvxSetup.cs:345    at
>   MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup.InitializeSecondary () [0x00065] in
>   D:\a\1\s\MvvmCross\Core\MvxSetup.cs:108    at
>   Eloptio.Mobile.Droid.Setup.InitializeSecondary () [0x00002] in
>   C:\Projects\el\trunk\Mobile\src\Eloptio.Mobile\Droid\Setup.cs:30

Comment: Is your "Core" project a Portable Class Library or .NET Standard Class Library?

Comment: .NET Standard 2.0

Comment: What changes did you make while upgrading from 6.3.1 to 6.4?

Comment: No changes, only nuget was updated

Comment: Any fix of this error?